Voltmeter Design for intermittent use
Designing a data acquisition and display system based on an iMXRT1062. My current voltmeter design measures the voltage on the main bus of the vehicle with an ADS1115 feeding the iMXRT. Unfortunately, that bus is powered after a diode (NTE53016) drop. The other side of the diode is direct connected to the battery, but I don't want a continuous load on the battery when the system isn't in use. What's the best way to measure the voltage while maintaining VERY high impedance when the system is powered off?

Just make sure all the chips you use have a shutdown mode and low shutdown current.

"the main bus of the vehicle" 12V 48V 500V?

14 or 28V depending on the application.


High-side switch (MOSFET or BJT).

Use a high-Z voltage divider (eg. 1MΩ to 10MΩ) and buffer the signal with a CMOS op-amp.


If in either case, if the load (or leakage) is 'much less' than battery self-discharge current it should be acceptable. In other words, if the battery self-discharge current is hundreds of uA or a mA then there is little point in designing for pA loading.

So, with #1, because the current is so low, I can assume that the dV across the MOSFET or BJT is zero, then feed this into a voltage divider and ADC? and with #2, the OpAmp is there to protect the ADC input from having voltage on it while the ADC is off?

Yes, the voltage across a well-saturated PNP transistor might be < 100mV and across a MOSFET it could be even lower. That's not a large amount and is relatively stable.

In the second case, the op-amp is because many converters, such as the SAR converters typically found on MCU chips are not so sanguine about having a high source impedance- they draw current in pulses with the average dependent on the sample  rate. Some chips have a buffer amplifier or PGA that does not have that issue. Typically the current with Vcc = 0 will be low enough that it's not a problem for the on-chip protection networks to deal very safely with it (whether op-amp or ADC), but verify. Some chips have 5V tolerant input that can withstand a few volts (not necessarily 5V) with Vdd=0.

OpAmp recommendation or a PNP and NPN package for SMT? Trying to stay pretty small. Thanks! This makes sense...

Use a PNP transistor to enable the current into the voltmeter, use an NPN to turn on the PNP
